# get the value of an element that is nested within an element linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an RSS xml that I am trying to extract info from and I have been using code that extracts the value from the element just fine. But now I have a problem that I have an element nested within another element which I can't figure out how to extract the information from.

Here is my xml structure that I'm using.

```
<item>
    <title>Nadal and Djokovic to lock horns again</title>
    <description>Rafael Nadal and Novak Djokovic will renew their rivalry in the Rome Masters final on Sunday</description>
    <link>http://www.espn.co.uk/tennis/sport/story/308417.html?CMP=OTC-RSS</link>
    <guid>http://www.espn.co.uk/tennis/sport/story/308417.html</guid>
    <pubDate>Sat, 17 May 2014 20:53:23 GMT</pubDate>
    <image>
        <url>www.espn.co.uk/PICTURES/CMS/66200/66275.2.jpg</url>
    </image>
</item>
```

I need to get the `<url>` element within the `<image>` element
for a specific `<item>`
So I have been using this code to get the other elements

```
var info = from article in xmlDocument.Descendants("item")
           where article.Element("title").Value.Equals("Serena sets up Errani final in Rome")
           select new
           {
               title = article.Element("url").Value,
               description = article.Element("description").Value,
               link = article.Element("link").Value,
               pubDate = article.Element("pubDate").Value,
           };
```

Please help me to get the value of the image url node.

Comment: Side note - when you are getting element's value via `Value` property you can get NullReferenceException if element was not found. So, consider to cast element to string - if element not found, then you will get null instead of exception

Comment: Thank you a lot Sergey Berezovskiy it worked a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string title = "Serena sets up Errani final in Rome";

var info = from i in xmlDocument.Descendants("item")
           where (string)i.Element("title") == title
           select new
           {
               title = title,
               description = (string)i.Element("description"),
               link = (string)i.Element("link"),
               pubDate = (string)i.Element("pubDate"),
               url = (string)i.Element("image").Element("url")
           };
```

If `image` element cab be missing, then you should check it before getting url:

```
var info = from i in xmlDocument.Descendants("item")
           where (string)i.Element("title") == title
           let image = i.Element("image")
           select new
           {
               title = title,
               description = (string)i.Element("description"),
               link = (string)i.Element("link"),
               pubDate = (string)i.Element("pubDate"),
               url = image == null ? null : (string)image.Element("url")
           };
```